# One-variable model calibration with lidaRtRee

Tags: r

row.names(res_pla_AL) =18

row.names(m_ALL) =18

package(lidaRtRee)

model_aba <- lidaRtRee::aba_build_model(res_pla_AL$G_m2_ha, m_ALL[, 1:53], transform = "boxcox", nmax = 3)

Error in leaps.setup(x, y, wt = weights, nbest = nbest, nvmax = nvmax,  :
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 4)

hello everyone, when I try to apply "aba_build_model" to get the set of statistical models with two excels files with the same number of rows, I come across this error that I can't solve. Can you help me please .